# WPF DataGrid, How to binding class properties as row?

Tags: c#, wpf

Model type is:

```
// Model
public class MyClass
{
    int A1 { get; set; }
    int A2 { get; set; }
    int A3 { get; set; }
    double B1 { get; set; }
    double B2 { get; set; }
    double B3 { get; set; }
}

...

private MyClass myClass1;
// Binding Source in ViewModel
public MyClass MyClass1
{
    Get => myClass1;
    Set => SetProperty(ref myClass1, value);
}
```

I want to bind the properties of MyClass to each row. MyClass1 property instance changes frequently.

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 123 |
| A2 | 456 |
| A3 | 789 |
| B1 | 0.0 |
| B2 | 1.1 |
| B3 | 2.2 |

In View, it will look like above, and Value Column is editable. Values edited in the View are updated directly via binding. How should I implement the View in this case? 3rd party libraries cannot be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a PropertyGrid for this.
If your software is for non commercial use you could use the [PorpertyGrid from Xceed](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/PropertyGrid)for example.

The WPF would look like `<xctk:PropertyGrid SelectedObject="{Binding MyClass}"/>`.
As seen in the link the control is highly ajustable.

[image]